# Java, URLConnection class, behaviour of timeouts

Tags: java, urlconnection

I'm working on a component in an android/java app, responsible (currently) for sending GET requests to a remote server. My code is based on this sample:

[HTTP Client Template.](http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/how-to-use-httpurlconnection-post-data-to-web-server/139)

I've utilized methods setConnectTimeout() and setReadTimeout() from the [URLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) class to my favor, however I lack full understanding of their impact, now say I specify a value of 10 seconds for both:

1. Does it mean it should give up after 10 seconds of inability to start a connection? and will never timeout if the connection is open & active?
2. Or giving up after 10 seconds from the moment of the call? even if say the connection was actually started successfully after 2 seconds, and it could not finish all data transfer during the next 8 seconds?
3. Or is it even another different case?

Also, the concept is clear for timing-out a connect attempt, but how does a receive timeout occur? because as far as I know the OS will automatically receive and hold the data sent to you in its local buffer even before you call for receiving, since the data could actually be sent to you before you make a call in your code, and thus the OS does what it does to guarantee that data isn't lost around.

So is my timeout value for receiving passed to the OS for it to handle stuff?

Forward thanks, I hope I did my part well in the question.